# Error during compilation, but the generated pdf looks correct

Tags: compiling

I am preparing a manuscript for a journal. I am using Latexila 2.12.0, and the tex version is TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea version 6.1.1

While compiling the file 'stack_exchan.tex' in the command line

```
pdflatex stack_exchan.tex
bibtex stack_exchan.aux
pdflatex stack_exchan.tex
pdflatex stack_exchan.tex
```

I do get errors for the `algorithm` environments, but the `stack_exchan.pdf` looks perfectly ok. Why am I getting the error during compilation, but the pdf looks good? Shall I send the latex files as it is to the journal?

Comment: Sometimes tex can recover from an error, but you should nevertheless better correct it.

Comment: and you should probably consider updating that latex installation (unrelated)